# Flutter, How to implement gesture for navigation transition?

Tags: flutter

How to implement gestures for navigation transition in Flutter?

For example, I want to implement navigation like CupertinoPageRoute (transition from bottom),

But I also want to swipe down to pop the navigation,

And also transition should match the gesture.

---

**Update1** :
After some research, I found that BuilderPageRoute can do custom navigation transition but I still can't implement the gesture.

Answer (score 2):

After done research, I have a solution. (I think it's an only solution).

It's very surprising that almost no one cares about this feature.

However, the only way to do that is to create a ***GestureController***

***How?***

In every navigator.push we need to have **PageRoute**

Inside PageRoute there have 2 important things

1. **AnimationController** - control the animation of transition.
2. **Navigator** - keep states of the navigation.

You will need to create a **GestureContrller** which detects the gesture then translate it to control animation progress.

When you first detect the gesture you need to call **navigator.didStartUserGesture**

After done the gesture you need to call **navigator.didStopUserGesture**.

Take a look at **_CupertinoBackGestureController** in Flutter source code for an example.

Comment: can you show me the sample code for this one? I also need to implement the same concept (transition is from right to the left when i swipe any Listview to the left like Whatsapp exactly when we want to see read and delivered time.